# Google Sheets: Query data with HH:MM format

Tags: google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula

Which query should I use to calculate **Total shift time** and **Total task time** grouped by Shift?

Google Sheets query doesn't allow me to sum Col2 or Col3 because it's formatted into HH:MM (I can't change it to number because source data is HH:MM).

[image]

Comment: may we assume that no shift begins before midnight and ends after?

Comment: It will sometimes. I was thinking to add 1 (+24:00h) If it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basis of a solution, but I had to format the Query columns as time manually and you would have to add 1 as you say to column C if the shift split across midnight:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:A,to_pure_number(B2:B),to_pure_number(C2:C)},"select Col1,max(Col3)-min(Col2),sum(Col3)-Sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null
 group by Col1 label Col1 'Shift',max(Col3)-min(Col2) 'Total',sum(Col3)-Sum(Col2) 'Task' "))
```

[image]

Here is a suggestion for handling shifts that go across midnight to the next day. It's necessary to add 1 to both time columns to get the right result. This assumes that the tasks are entered in the right order in each shift, or at least that the first task is entered first for each shift:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:A,to_pure_number(B2:B+(B2:B<vlookup(A2:A,{A2:A,B2:B},2,false))),
to_pure_number(C2:C+(C2:C<vlookup(A2:A,{A2:A,B2:B},2,false)))},"select Col1,max(Col3)-min(Col2),sum(Col3)-Sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null
 group by Col1 label Col1 'Shift',max(Col3)-min(Col2) 'Total',sum(Col3)-Sum(Col2) 'Task' "))
```

[image]

Comment: That's good! I will try and think of a way of adding the split-shifts - it's not completely straightforward.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJc8K.png

Would it be possible to add to the same query a Specific Task time (Task B time) and merge all tasks text into the same column (Tasks done).

I was doing it with google-sheets formulas but its a heavy load

Comment: I think the task time would be a separate query because you're either doing a select where Col4='B' or a group by on shift as well as Task. I think the tasks per shift would just be an ordinary pull-down formula (maybe post it as a separate question though and see whether anyone else has a good idea for it?).

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should change your source data so that the shift pattern is formatted to include both date and time.  Then follow this procedure to do the correct arithmetic:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/10/19/calculating-time-google-sheets/